# How to convert Maven project to Gradle project in MyEclipse?

Tags: gradle, maven-3

We have maven (pom.xml) project and want to convert this into using gradle.(build.gradle). Can anyone tell me how to convert maven project to gradle project?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are articles that can be found on google that can help. Example - http://www.jayway.com/2013/05/12/getting-started-with-gradle/

Assuming this is a [java](/questions/tagged/java) project. The simplest thing to get started is - create `build.gradle` in the same directory as `pom.xml`.

```
apply plugin: 'java'   #Java project - standard maven directory structure expected

repositories {
   mavenCentral() #Download dependencies from maven central
}

dependencies {
   compile = "org.apache.ant:ant:1.8.1"   #As an example - ant dependency
}
```

And that is it as a simple starting point - Dependencies have been declared and the project is a [java](/questions/tagged/java) one. To run jUnit tests - `gradle test`, to jar `gradle jar`.

If you want to invoke a `main()` function

```
apply plugin: 'application'
mainClassName=com.coyote.Foo
```

To invoke `gradle run`

All the information on [gradle](/questions/tagged/gradle) is available on http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/userguide.html